# always get a "not a GROUP BY expression" exception

Tags: sql, oracle

The select part is fine, I can run it and get result, but if I insert the query result into a table, the "not a group by expression" exception was thrown, see my sql statement below:

```
INSERT INTO RAWDATA_FACT 
                     (
                         LINEITEMID
                        ,CALENDARYEAR
                        ,CALENDARQUARTER
                        ,CALENDARMONTH
                        ,DEPARTMENTID
                        ,PRODUCTID
                        ,DEALERID
                        ,ACTUALVALUE
                        ,TARGETVALUE
                        ,AGGREGATION
                        ,TODATE

                        ,CREATEDATE
                        ,BATCH_ID
                     )      
select  parentid
                            ,calendaryear
                                      ,calendarquarter 
                                      ,calendarmonth 
                                      ,departmentid
                                      ,productid
                                      ,dealerid
       ,sum(case when unaryoperator = '-' then actualvalue * (-1)
                 when unaryoperator = '~' then actualvalue * 0
                 else actualvalue
            end
                                                     ) actualvalue
       ,sum(case when unaryoperator = '-' then targetvalue * (-1)
                 when unaryoperator = '~' then targetvalue * 0
                                                       else targetvalue
                                           end
                                                     ) targetvalue

                                      ,aggregation
                                      ,todate

                                      ,sysdate createdate
                                      ,'201808' batch_id--v_batch_ID
                     from 
                     (
                                   select   
                                            x.parentid
                                                     , x.unaryoperator
           , y.calendaryear
                                                     , y.calendarquarter
                                                     , y.calendarmonth
                                                     , y.departmentid
                                                     , y.productid 
                                                     , y.dealerid
                                                     , y.actualvalue
                                                     , y.targetvalue
                                                     , y.aggregation
                                                     , y.todate
                                   from
                                                  (select substr(lineitemid,instr(lineitemid,'_')+1) lineitemid, 
                                                                              parentid, unaryoperator from lineitem_temp where levelid = 14 /*v_cur_level*/) x
                                   inner join

                                                  (select lineitemid,calendaryear, calendarquarter, calendarmonth, departmentid, productid, dealerid,
                                                                              coalesce(actualvalue,0) actualvalue,coalesce(targetvalue,0) targetvalue,
                                                                   aggregation, todate
                                                                   from RAWDATA_FACT where BATCH_ID = '201808'/*v_batch_ID*/) y --eg. 201809
                                   on x.lineitemid = y.lineitemid 
                                    --parent node's id contains "_" will not take part in calculation from current level to parent level
                                   where regexp_like(x.parentid , '^\d+$') and not exists
                                   --parent node contains formula will not participate calculation from current level to parent level
                                   (select 1 from LINEITEM_TEMP where lineitemid = x.parentid and custommember is not null)
                     ) t
                     GROUP BY 
                          t.parentid
                        , t.calendaryear
                        , t.calendarquarter
                        , t.calendarmonth
                        , t.departmentid
                        , t.productid
                        , t.dealerid
                        , t.aggregation
                        , t.todate
                     ;
```

who can tell me why? is there a way to insert the result into that table? If I run the select parts, it works fine, but if I want to insert the result into that table, it reports that exception.

Comment: Can you run the SELECT part alone, i.e. without INSERT?

Comment: yes, I can, it gives me query result

Comment: Any triggers involved?

Comment: I use Oracel 12c, and there is a factsurrogatekey field is an automatic increment field, is it related to this?

Comment: Maybe add this column to group by? ,sysdate createdate . '201808' batch_id--v_batch_ID

Comment: Not as a solution but just for diagnosis purposes, run this: `alter session set "_complex_view_merging" = false;` and then try your `INSERT` again.  Also, which exact version of Oracle are you on?  There are relatively recent bugs in Oracle that can cause this.